# Unicode to ANSI

Tags: c#, string, encoding

How can I convert a unicode to ANSI?

Example I have the following unicode username:

```
очередной
```

and I call this import method:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetTempPathA")]
public static extern uint GetTempPath(uint nBufferLength, [Out()]
System.Text.StringBuilder lpBuffer);
```

I receive the following result:

```
C:\Users\A690~1\AppData\Local\Temp\
```

Now I've tried multiple encoding things like:

```
Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Environment.UserName));
Encoding.GetEncoding(1250).GetString(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Environment.UserName));
Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetString(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Environment.UserName));
```

but none of them gave me the same result as the import method. How can I properly convert a unicode string to ANSI so that it gives me the same result as the import method?

Comment: your import method doesn't convert anything, it returns the path to your users temp directory. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/desktop/aa364992(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: My question was how can I convert the string 'очередной' to receive 'A690~1'

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`GetTempPathW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364992(v=vs.85).aspx) method instead of the `GetTempPathA` method. The `W` makes it Unicode, which is what you need for your Unicode characters.

Trying to convert your Unicode to ASCII (which is impossible when you want to use characters from the non-ASCII range) will not solve the issue.

Comment: Why do you tell me to use GetTempPathW when my question was how can I convert the string 'очередной' to receive 'A690~1' ?

Comment: You can't. Simple as that @user7436839